# Bash, lines of a variable contain substring?

Tags: string, bash, line, contains, bats-core

While trying to write a robust bash method that detects whether a variable that consists of multiple lines of text, contains a substring (that may contain spaces) I am experiencing some difficulties. Three functions were written and I wrote some tests for them using the [BATS](https://github.com/sstephenson/bats) framework. The functions and the accompanying tests on which they fail, are included below.

### Method I

```
lines_contain_string() {
    local substring="$1"
    shift
    local lines=("$@")
    
    local found_substring="NOTFOUND"

    for i in "${lines[@]}"; do
        if [[ $i == *"$substring"* ]]; then
            echo "FOUND"
            local found_substring="FOUND"
        fi
    done

    if [ "$found_substring" == "NOTFOUND" ]; then
        echo "NOTFOUND"
    fi
}
```

This fails on test:

```
EXAMPLE_LINES=$(cat <<-END
First line
second line 
third line 
sometoken
END
)

@test "Substring in first line is found in lines by lines_contain_string." {
    contained_substring="First line"
    
    actual_result=$(lines_contain_string "$contained_substring" "\${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    #actual_result=$(lines_contain_string_with_space "$contained_substring" "\${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    EXPECTED_OUTPUT="FOUND"
        
    assert_equal "$actual_result" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"
}
```

So the first method does not catch all substrings.

### Method II

And for the second method:

```
lines_contain_string_with_space() {
    local substring="$1"
    local lines="$@"
    if [ "$lines" == "" ]; then
        echo "NOTFOUND"
    # shellcheck disable=SC2154
    elif [[ "$lines" =~ "$substring" ]]; then
        echo "FOUND"; 
    else
        echo "NOTFOUND";
    fi
}
```

This seems to return false positive/seems to always return "FOUND", for example, on test:

```
EXAMPLE_LINES=$(cat <<-END
First line
second line 
third line 
sometoken
END
)

@test "lines_contain_string returns NOTFOUND on non-existing substring." {
    contained_substring="Non-existing-substring"
    
    #actual_result=$(lines_contain_string "$contained_substring" "\${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    actual_result=$(lines_contain_string_with_space "$contained_substring" "\${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    EXPECTED_OUTPUT="NOTFOUND"
        
    assert_equal "$actual_result" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"
}
```

### Method III

This method is provided by choroba:

```
string_in_lines() {
    local substring=$1
    shift
    local lines=$1
    if [[ $lines = *"$substring"* ]] ; then
        echo FOUND
    else
        echo NOTFOUND
    fi
}
```

And calling it with test:

```
@test "Substring in first line is found in lines by lines_contain_string." {
    contained_substring="First line"
    
    read -p "EXAMPLE_LINES=$EXAMPLE_LINES"

    #actual_result=$(lines_contain_string "$contained_substring" "\${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    #actual_result=$(lines_contain_string_with_space "$contained_substring" "\${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    actual_result=$(string_in_lines "$contained_substring" "\${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    EXPECTED_OUTPUT="FOUND"
        
    assert_equal "$actual_result" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"
}
```

Produces output:

```
 ✗ Substring in first line is found in lines by lines_contain_string.
   (from function `assert_equal' in file test/no_server_required/preserves_server/../../libs/bats-assert/src/assert_equal.bash, line 40,
    in test file test/no_server_required/preserves_server/test_parsing.bats, line 35)
     `assert_equal "$actual_result" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"' failed
   EXAMPLE_LINES=First line
   second line 
   third line 
   sometoken
   -- values do not equal --
   expected : FOUND
   actual   : NOTFOUND
   --
```

### Question

How can one echo "FOUND"/"NOTFOUND" in a bash function, based on whether an incoming variable, consisting of multiple lines, contains a substring that may contain spaces? (And test it accordingly.)

### Note

Since my tests also fail on the method provided by choroba, which I assume has a large likelihood of being successful, I expect my test functions are not correct. I updated the question accordingly.

The comments by choroba suggested the backslash in: `"${EXAMPLE_LINES}" was incorrect. I tested whether that was incorrect, and it turned out it was incorrect. So the solution was to write the test as:

```
@test "Substring in first line is found in lines by lines_contain_string." {
    contained_substring="First line"

    #actual_result=$(lines_contain_string "$contained_substring" "${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    #actual_result=$(lines_contain_string_with_space "$contained_substring" "${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    actual_result=$(string_in_lines "$contained_substring" "${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    EXPECTED_OUTPUT="FOUND"
        
    assert_equal "$actual_result" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"
}

@test "lines_contain_string returns NOTFOUND on non-existing substring." {
    contained_substring="Non-existing-substring"
    
    #actual_result=$(lines_contain_string "$contained_substring" "${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    #actual_result=$(lines_contain_string_with_space "$contained_substring" "${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    actual_result=$(string_in_lines "$contained_substring" "${EXAMPLE_LINES}")
    EXPECTED_OUTPUT="NOTFOUND"
        
    assert_equal "$actual_result" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `=` with a wildcard pattern.

```sh
string_in_lines() {
    local substring=$1
    shift
    local lines=$1
    if [[ $lines = *"$substring"* ]] ; then
        echo FOUND
    else
        echo NOTFOUND
    fi
}
```

Comment: is there a difference between `=` and `==` inside `[[ ]]` in bash?

Comment: Running my test, e.g. the last one that I included in my question, on your answer returns `NOTFOUND`, instead of `FOUND`. I assume this is because my tests are not written correctly. Yet to exclude this option I would like to ask: have you tested your function?/Do you see a mistake in my test?

Comment: I don't know where `@test` and `assert_equal` come from, so I tested just string equality `[[ $string1 = $string2 ]] || echo WRONG`.  Therefore I don't know why you use the backslash in `actual_result=$(string_in_lines "$contained_substring" "\${EXAMPLE_LINES}")`.

Comment: @Fravadona No difference between the two (Outside of `[[ ]]`, POSIX only specifies `=` in `[ ]`/`test` so `==` shouldn't be used there if you're aiming for POSIX compatibility.).

Comment: @choroba, thank you for your feedback. The `@test` and `assert_equal` came out of the `bats` (framework). Your pondering was spot on, it turned out the backslash in my tests was incorrect. I should have written: `actual_result=$(string_in_lines "$contained_substring" "${EXAMPLE_LINES}")` instead of `..."\${EXAMPLE_LINES}"..`. It was there because I, *wrongly*, thought that was the way to pass variables containing multiple lines to a function in bash, based on what I thought I saw in the past (instead of documentation).